# In Angular Reactive Form, why does html select not clear value?

Tags: angular, select, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 13 Reactive Forms.

I have a simple method in each *reusable* component that clears the value of whatever has been selected/chosen. It works with my input and autocomplete, but not select. Here is the method and relevant ts:

```
@Input() parentFormGroup!: FormGroup;
@Input() selectFormControlName!: string;
@Input() selectAbstractControl!: AbstractControl;
@Input() options: string[] = ['Rain', 'Sleet', 'Hail', 'Mist'];
@Input() includeClearButton: boolean = true;

ngOnInit() {
    this._setUpForm();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._removeControl();
  }

  private _setUpForm() {
    this.parentFormGroup.addControl(
      this.selectFormControlName,
      this.selectAbstractControl
    );
  }

  private _removeControl() {
    this.parentFormGroup.removeControl(this.selectFormControlName);
  }

  clearInput() {
    this.selectAbstractControl.patchValue('');
    this.selectAbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

and here is the html:

```
  <select>
    <option hidden selected value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options">{{ option }}</option>
  </select>
  <button *ngIf="includeClearButton" type="button" (click)="clearInput()">
    X
  </button>
```

Surprisingly, I haven't found any answers online. Enough so that I wondered for a while if it was a typo on my part, because I don't know why patchValue() and updateValueAndValidity() would work on input and autocomplete, but not selects.

Any ideas where I have gone wrong here?

Comment: How do you bind the value of `select` to your `parentFormGroup`?

Comment: By using addControl in the setUpForm method.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It's because I forgot to add [formGroup]="parentFormGroup" to the parent div and  [formControlName]="selectFormControlName" to the select element itself.